# How does .utf8 encoding exactly works with json data encoding?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a function `fetchData()` in APIManager Class that takes json response from url. Called it in my `viewDidLoad` method. I'm little bit confused how .utf8 exactly works here.

```
let api = APIManager()
let request = api.fetchData()

request.done { response in

    if let json = response.data(using: .utf8) {
        let productCategories = try? 
        JSONDecoder().decode(ProductCategory.self, from: json)

        for product in (productCategories?.electronics)! {
            print(product.name)
        }    
    }   
}
```

and here is my ProductCategory Class, in case you wanna see

```
class ProductCategory: Codable {    
    var electronics: [Product]
    var furniture: [Product]
    var homeAppliances : [Product]

    enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey{
        case electronics = "Electronics"
        case furniture = "Furniture"
        case homeAppliances = "Home Appliance"
    }
}
```

Comment: utf8 it is just how the JSON string is usually encoded. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Actually, I thought it to be something more complicated. Thanks!

Comment: UTF-8 is just a [variable width character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).